# Equal output values given for Multiclass Classification

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to build a CNN for predicting the number of fingers in an image, using PyTorch. The network:

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.Layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2)),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2)),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(1, 1)),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2)),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(1, 1)),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2)),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(1, 1)),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2)),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(1, 1)),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
        nn.ReLU(),
        )

        self.Layer2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(1536, 100),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(100, 6),
        nn.Softmax()
        )
        self.optimizer = optimizers.Adadelta(self.parameters())

    def forward(self, X):
        X = self.Layer1(X)
        print(X.shape)
        X = self.Layer2(X.reshape(1, 1536))
        X = X.squeeze()

        return X

    def calc_loss(self, X, num):
        out = self.forward(X).unsqueeze(dim=0)
        print("Output: "+str(out))
        target = torch.tensor([num], dtype=torch.int64).cuda()
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        loss = criterion(out, target)
        return loss

    def train_step(self, X, Y):
        loss = self.calc_loss(X, Y)
        print(loss)
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
```

However, after the training is complete, all predictions have almost the same values (around 0.15 ~ 0.18).

It appears as though the network averages out the output probabilities to minimize loss, instead of learning the actual values.

I get the same result whether I use Softmax for the last layer with cross-entropy loss, or Sigmoid with binary cross-entropy, MSE, or SmoothL1Loss.

In case of using Adam optimizer, I get similar results, only in the range of 1e-12 ~ 1e-14.

What am I missing?

Comment: To be honest, your implementation is a little bit confusing, why not to split off the model implementation and the training loop? It will make your debugging much easier

Comment: I wanted to keep all network operations separate from the data operations. All data is loaded from a different file and fed to the model from that file.

Comment: `train_step` is called multiple times in a loop for different values of X and Y for the file mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: I see.. Did you try to overfit your model on a single batch? just for testing, to be sure that the everything works fine?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. For a single class, it works fine. When I introduce more classes, the output gets averaged over those classes. For example, if I overfit for classes 1 and 5, the output is of the form ~ [0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5]

Comment: Are you using `torch` `DataSet`? If not, did you one-hot your labels, because if it works for one class, and fails for more, maybe the problem is in labels encoding.

Comment: I'm not using torch DataSet. However, using one-hot for `CrossEntropyLoss` gave errors. After some search, I found that PyTorch's CrossEntropyLoss takes an integral value as the target, representing the class index. For other loss functions, I have used one-hot encodings.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are right, for `CrossEntropyLoss` targets should be 1D Tensor with values of class index from 0 to C-1. Are your classes started from 0?

Comment: Yes, they index from 0

Comment: Ok, I am worrying about criterion, looks like you initialize new one every time she you compute loss. I think it is better to init it once in __init__(), like optimizer. I am not sure, but CrossEntropy performs onehot encoding anyway, and in your model you initialize new loss for each new batch, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: You're right! I overlooked this mistake.

Comment: However, it does not change the result...

Comment: ok, I looked once again at your problem and for `CrossEntropyLoss` you need raw output w/o Softmax.

Comment: `CrossEntropyLoss` already includes `softmax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `CrossEntropyLoss`, you don't need to use `Softmax` in your `forward`. It is already included to `CrossEntropyLoss`, so you need the "raw" output. But, if you need `Softmax` during inference time, use `NLLLoss` + 'Softmax' instead.

You can find more info [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/does-nllloss-handle-log-softmax-and-softmax-in-the-same-way/8835)

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thank you!

Comment: You welcome! Sorry I didn't notice it from the first look. My bad)